# Build an improved GSM antenna for arduino mkr gsm 1400

Tags: remote-control, system-design, mkr1000

I want to use an Arduino MKR GSM 1400 in my area wich has a bad connectivity on mobile internet. On my phone it's very weak and if i drive to the next village it works sometimes on the arduino with the given standard antenna but I want it to work in a wider range. Is there any antenna available specifically for mobile connections wich you can put on a arduino? And how do you call them and where can I buy such a thing or even build it myself? Do you have any suggestions for such an antenna? And is there something I can improve with just using software to strengthen the signal?

Answer (score 1):

On one end of the MKR GSM 1400 is a *U.FL* antenna connector.  To that you need to connect a *U.FL To Female SMA Adaptor*.  That adaptor can then screw into an *SMA GSM Antenna* of your choice.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for such an SMA antenna wich has a wide range? And where can I find that specific adapter??

Comment: I get the adaptors from eBay. I can't recommend a specific antenna, but the ones with a long cable and a magnetic mount (that are intended to go on top of cars, etc) would allow you to place the antenna in a high location where you can get better signal.

Comment: @The_javascript_King The connector is one thing, but antenna performance is dependent on antenna type and gain. Try to compare gain values (in dBi) of the antennas you're buying -- the higher, the better.